# One controller one service

Tags: service, architecture, controller

I see more and more suggestions about having a service for every controller when using service pattern.
This seems to me to be odd, and a bad practice. But my major concern is, did I misunderstand something about the service pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you were to look at the problem a little abstracted from what's right and what's wrong in the theory (or in `suggestions`). Then there's only the team who will have to support such architectural decision in future. Maybe if it feels wrong from the beginning, than it's not worth spending time on.

Comment: Thanks I know the question seems a little black and white, which is not the purpose, but it's hard to explain it better since there is not much to it. On that note I agree with you, and thanks for the confirmation.